# Trouble creating AVD on ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I downloaded the ADT bundle for Mac from developer.android.com, unzipped it and opened up the ADT executable but I cannot create an AVD. I get a null error when I do it through ADT and an error that the file /Users/my computer name/.android/avd/AVD name.ini does not exist. I tried physically creating the folder but to no avail.

Comment: Did you install the ADT Bundle? Did you open Eclipse?

Comment: What i did was unzip the folder and open ADT which opened up Eclipse with the ADT add on.

Comment: It sounds like ADT can't find the SDK. Have you installed the Android SDK?

Comment: Yup. I open up the android executable in the sdk/tools folder and it says all the necessary packages are installed.